# How can I train with my own dataset with darkflow?

Tags: yolo, darknet, darkflow

I'm a beginner with some programming experince. I'm trying to train darkflow with my own dataset. I'm following these instructions.

https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

So far I have done the following steps.

- installed darkflow and the relevant modules
- created test images and made annotations (Pascal VOC).

  ```
             https://ibb.co/y4HmtGz  

             https://ibb.co/GkxLshK
  ```

If I have understood correctly the darkflow training requires Pascal VOC?

My problem is that I don't know how to start the training. How can I start the training process and how can I test if the neuralnet is working? Am I supposed to get weights as a result of training?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use pre-trained weights from [here](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/). Download `cfg` and `weights`.

Assuming you have darkflow installed, you can train your network like this:

```
flow --model cfg/<your-config-filename>.cfg --load bin/<filename>.weights --train --annotation train/Annotations --dataset train/Images --epoch 100 --gpu 1.0
```

If you want to train your network from scratch w/o using any pre-trained weights,
you can do this:

```
flow --model cfg/<your-config-filename>.cfg --train --annotation train/Annotations --dataset train/Images --epoch 100 --gpu 1.0
```

After the training starts, model checkpoints are saved inside `ckpt` directory. You can load latest checkpoint and test on sample images.